# PE Standard User cannot view Visualforce page due to Insufficient Privileges

Tags: visualforce, professional-edition, userlicense

I'm working on a professional edition with API enabled and I have a VF page rendering as PDF, with a standard Quote controller.
When users with the Standard User profile try to view this VF page they get the Insufficient Privileges error message.

Any idea why?

I feel its not related to the code but still, this is the page's code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" renderAs="PDF" showHeader="false" 
           applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
    <html>    
        <head>    
            <style>
                 !!styling removed to shorten the code
            </style>
        </head>    
        <body>       
            <div class="header">
                <left>
                    <apex:image height="50" value="{!$Resource.PDF_Logo}" alt="" title=""/>
                </left>              
            </div>

            <div class="footer">    
                <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div> 
            </div>

            <div class="content">                                   
                <div>
                    <center>
                        <h4>SERVICE QUOTE #{!Quote.QuoteNumber}</h4>
                    </center>
                </div>

                <table style="width:100%" class="table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">Quote for: {!Quote.Account.Name}</td>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">
                           <apex:outputText value="Quote Preparation Date: {0,date, EEE, d MMM yyyy}">
                               <apex:param value="{!Quote.CreatedDate}" />
                           </apex:outputText>                    
                        </td> 
                    </tr>               
                    <tr>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">Prepared for: {!Quote.Contact.Name}</td>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">
                           <apex:outputText value="Quote Expiration Date: {0,date, EEE, d MMM yyyy}">
                               <apex:param value="{!Quote.ExpirationDate}" />
                           </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3"></td>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">
                           <apex:outputText value="Service Request Date: {0,date, EEE, d MMM yyyy}">
                               <apex:param value="{!Quote.Service_Request_Date__c}" />
                           </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                
                    <tr>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">Account Manager: {!Quote.Opportunity.owner.Name}</td>
                        <!-- <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">Minimum Service Term: {!Quote.Minimum_Service_Term__c} Months</td> -->
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">
                            <apex:outputText value="Minimum Service Term: {0, number} Months">  
                                <apex:param value="{!Quote.Minimum_Service_Term__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </td>                         
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" style="border-left:0px; border-right:0px; height:25px;">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>   

                    <tr class="txtLeft tableHeader" >
                        <th colspan="6">1. Location</th>   
                    </tr>                           
                    <tr>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">Site: {!Quote.Opportunity.Site_Name__c}</td>
                        <td class="txtLeft" colspan="3">Link: {!Quote.Opportunity.Link_Name__c}</td>               
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="border:none; height:30px;" colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="tableHeader">
                        <th colspan="6">2. Pricing Model: {!Quote.Pricing_Model__c}</th>
                    </tr>                  
                    <tr class="tableSubHeader">
                        <th>
                            <img src="/img/check.gif" />
                        </th>                    
                        <th style="width:25%">
                            {!IF(ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_Products_Column_Header__c), 'Products', Quote.PDF_s_Products_Column_Header__c)}
                        </th>

                        <th style="width:19%">
                            <!-- {!Quote.PDF_s_Quantity_Column_Header__c} -->
                            {!IF(ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_Quantity_Column_Header__c), CASE(Quote.Pricing_Model__c, 'Fixed Rate', 'Quantity / Managed Capacity (Mbps)', 
                                                           'Managed Capacity (95/5)', 'Quantity / Minimum Managed Capacity (Mbps)', 
                                                           'Generated Capacity (95/5)', 'Quantity / Minimum Managed Capacity (Mbps)',
                                                           'No pricing Model'), Quote.PDF_s_Quantity_Column_Header__c)}
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:19%">
                            <!-- {!Quote.PDF_s_Unit_Price_Column_Header__c} -->
                            {!IF(ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_Unit_Price_Column_Header__c), CASE(Quote.Pricing_Model__c, 'Fixed Rate', 'Unit Price / Price per Burstable Capacity (Mbps)', 
                                                           'Managed Capacity (95/5)', 'Unit Price / Price per Mbps (Managed)', 
                                                           'Generated Capacity (95/5)', 'Unit Price / Price per Mbps (Generated)',
                                                           'No pricing Model'), Quote.PDF_s_Unit_Price_Column_Header__c)}
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:19%">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.PDF_s_NRC_Column_Header__c}" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_NRC_Column_Header__c))}"/>
                            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_NRC_Column_Header__c)}">
                                NRC <br/> (Non Recurring Charges)
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <!-- {!IF(ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_NRC_Column_Header__c), 'NRC (Non Recurring Charges)', Quote.PDF_s_NRC_Column_Header__c)} -->
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:19%">
                            <!-- {!Quote.PDF_s_MRC_Column_Header__c} -->

                            {!IF(ISBLANK(Quote.PDF_s_MRC_Column_Header__c), CASE(Quote.Pricing_Model__c, 'Fixed Rate', 'MRC (Monthly Recurring Charges)', 
                                                           'Managed Capacity (95/5)', 'MRC (Monthly Recurring Charges)', 
                                                           'Generated Capacity (95/5)', 'MRC (Monthly Recurring Charges)*',
                                                           'No pricing Model'), Quote.PDF_s_MRC_Column_Header__c)}
                        </th>                                                            
                    </tr>

                    <!--  MRC Table -->
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.QuoteLineItems}" var="quoteItem">
                        <tr class="{!CASE(quoteItem.Product2.Charges_Recurrance__c, 'MRC', '', 'hidden')}">
                            <td>
                                <img src="/img/check.gif" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtLeft">
                                {!quoteItem.Product2.Name}
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">
                                {!quoteItem.Quantity}
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">                                   
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                    <apex:param value="{!quoteItem.UnitPrice}"/>  
                                </apex:outputText>                                  
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">                                   
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                    <apex:param value="{!quoteItem.Non_Recurring_Charges_NRC__c}"/>  
                                </apex:outputText>                                  
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">                                   
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                    <apex:param value="{!quoteItem.Monthly_Recurring_Charges_MRC__c}"/>  
                                </apex:outputText>                                  
                            </td>                               
                        </tr>                                         
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <!--  NRC Table -->
                    <apex:repeat value="{!Quote.QuoteLineItems}" var="quoteItem">
                        <tr class="{!CASE(quoteItem.Product2.Charges_Recurrance__c, 'MRC', 'hidden', '')}">
                            <td>
                                <img src="/img/check.gif" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtLeft">
                                {!quoteItem.Product2.Name}
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">
                                {!quoteItem.Quantity}
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">                                   
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                    <apex:param value="{!quoteItem.UnitPrice}"/>  
                                </apex:outputText>                                  
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">                                   
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                    <apex:param value="{!quoteItem.Non_Recurring_Charges_NRC__c}"/>  
                                </apex:outputText>                                  
                            </td>
                            <td class="txtRight">                                   
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                    <apex:param value="{!quoteItem.Monthly_Recurring_Charges_MRC__c}"/>  
                                </apex:outputText>                                  
                            </td>                               
                        </tr>                                         
                    </apex:repeat>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" class="txtLeft" style="font-style:italic;">
                            Notes:

                            <apex:outputtext value="{!Quote.Notes__c}" escape="false"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" style="border:none; height:30">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="tableHeader">
                        <th colspan="4">3. Service Quote Total (Excluding VAT &amp; Tax)</th>
                        <th class="textCenter">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                <apex:param value="{!quote.NRC_excl_VAT_TAX__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText> 
                        </th>
                        <th class="textCenter">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                <apex:param value="{!quote.MRC_excl_VAT_TAX__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText>                     
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="">
                        <th colspan="4">VAT &amp; Tax</th>
                        <th class="textCenter">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                <apex:param value="{!quote.NRC_VAT_Tax__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </th>
                        <th class="textCenter">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                <apex:param value="{!quote.MRC_VAT_Tax__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText>                    
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tableHeader">
                        <th colspan="4">Service Quote Total (Including VAT &amp; Tax)</th>
                        <th class="textCenter">
                             <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                <apex:param value="{!quote.NRC_Grand_Total__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText>                   
                        </th>
                        <th class="textCenter">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Quote.Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">  
                                <apex:param value="{!quote.MRC_Grand_Total__c}"/>  
                            </apex:outputText>                    
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="6" style="border-left:0px;border-right:0px">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tableHeader" style="{!IF(Quote.QuoteLineItems.size > 8, 'page-break-before:always','')}">
                        <th colspan="6">4. General Terms</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" class="txtLeft" style="font-style:italic; height:30px;">
                            <apex:outputtext value="{!Quote.Terms_and_Conditions__c}" escape="false"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                
                </table>      
            </div>  
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: does the standard profile has permission to access the page ? you can use this  reference :  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_visualforce_access.htm

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the security on the page itself?
Setup | Develop | Pages then, look at the list of pages, and select the security option for the page in question. Make sure that everyone has access to the page.

Comment: I think that in the PE you cannot access the security settings for pages